# How to make two Jhipster webapp version coexist in Google Cloud App Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, jhipster

Is it posible to deploy two versions of a Jhipster app in Google Cloud App Engine (using jhipster gae and gradlew appengineDeploy -Pgae -Pprod-gae) in a way that the can coexist?

When I deploy (gradlew appengineDeploy -Pgae -Pprod-gae), the new version overwrites the old one.

Comment: Can you set a service name with JHipster? It should because JHipster support dispatch on GAE: https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/#deploy-to-google-app-engine

Comment: Sorry, but where do you see that? Thanks